# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Common, Version=12.0.0.0' with LabDefaultTemplate.11.xaml

Tags: mtm

Currently we are upgrading our tfs server from 2012RTM to 2013update3.

We encounter following exception when to do BDT on Lab center.
Build controller: tfs2013 update3
Test controller: tfs2012 update 4
Test agent: tfs2012 update 4
Lab template: LabDefaultTemplate.11.xaml

Exception details:

> Exception Message: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Common, Version=12.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. (type
>   FileNotFoundException) Exception Stack Trace:    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Lab.Workflow.Activities.ExecuteRemoteTestRun2.TestRunCreation.CreateTestRun(CodeActivityContext
>   context, ITestManagementService testManager,
>   ITestManagementTeamProject project)    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Lab.Workflow.Activities.ExecuteRemoteTestRun2.TestRunCreation.Execute(CodeActivityContext
>   context)    at
>   System.Activities.CodeActivity`1.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance
>   instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager) 
>   at
>   System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor
>   executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)

Comment: Can't you update also the test controller and the test agent to TFS2013 Update 3?

Comment: Yes, I have also tried this scenario. But it throws the same error.